# Distinguish between existing node and empty node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 Nodes

`<example/>` and `<example></example>`.

How can i distinguish between them?

In my mind the first is `<xsl:when test="example">` and the second is
`<xsl:when test="example = ''">`.

I dont think these are right
I am confused by this. Can anyone please clarify?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note: The test="example" is a test if the node exists, it exists in both cases and therefore is true for both. This applies also to the second case as both example child nodes contain an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The XML Information Set and the XPath data model state that there is no difference between `<example/>` and `<example></example>`:

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#omitted  (Item D.7)

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xpath-datamodel-20070123/#ElementNode  (where you find no property distinguishing the two different syntaxes for an empty element: if the element has no children using either syntax, the element node is constructed the same way)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i distinguish between them?

You can't distinguish between them in an XML tool because they're two different ways to serialize exactly the same XML node tree.  If your application *needs* to distinguish between the two cases<sup>1</sup> then you'll need to use some sort of non-XML tool, either exclusively or as a pre-processing step.

For example, if you know that there are no instances of the string "`/>`" within the original file other than as part of an empty element tag, then you could do a textual replacement on the original file (treated as text) to change all instances of

```
/>
```

into

```
 _wasEmpty="yes"/>
```

(including the leading space) before parsing the result as XML, and then your XSLT can distinguish using `<xsl:when test="example[_wasEmpty = 'yes']">`.

---

<sup>1</sup> I (and many others on SO) would argue that an application that claims to be XML based but which needs to distinguish between things that XML says are equivalent is fundamentally broken - the correct approach here is to talk to whoever designed the format that you are consuming and ask them to change it to distinguish the cases in an XML-compatible way such as using `xsi:nil`.  But I'm pragmatic and appreciate that sometimes this isn't possible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

They are indistinguishable by design. You could also write

```
<example   />
```

or

```
<example  ></example   >
```

and those would also be indistinguishable.

These variations are designed to give some flexibility to people authoring or generating XML, without complicating applications that consume XML.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion - both forms of empty element are equal and it is not possible to distinguish them.

`<xsl:when test="example">` tests if there exists some element named "example".

`<xsl:when test="example = ''">` tests if the string value of the element is the empty string.

Comment: The second claim is not true, as it only tests if the string value of the element is the empty string.  It would test true for `<example><?cursor?></example>` but in that case the `<example>` element is not empty.  To test an `<example>` child element is empty use `test="not(example/node())"`.

Comment: You are right - my fault. I improved my answer. Thanks for your comment.